# Excel chart component recommendations

Tags: excel, charts, business-intelligence, dashboard

I have to build an analytic dashboard with Excel, and would like to know whether there is any chart library you would recommend.

The charts should be attractive and easy to use by standard users.

I've tried [Microcharts](http://www.bonavistasystems.com/index.html), and they look very promising, but I'd like to evaluate more options before reaching a decision.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for custom charts in Excel, two resources that I turn to first are:

- Jon Peltier of [Peltier Technical Services](http://peltiertech.com/index.html)
- Chandoo of [Pointy Haired Dilbert](http://chandoo.org/wp/)

For dashboards, specifically I would recommend the six part series by Robert "[Creating KPI Dashboards in Microsoft Excel](http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/08/20/create-kpi-dashboards-excel-1/)" (Robert also has a blog, [Clearly and Simply](http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/), that has great content and a list of other sites that you may find useful under the sidebar "Blogs and Links")

For the theory behind dashboards, [Stephen Few](http://www.perceptualedge.com/) has a book "Information Dashboard Design: The Effective Visual Communication of Data" that goes into detail on best practices. He also wrote and [article about dashboards](http://www.tdwi.org/print.aspx?id=7487) focusing on good vs. bad designs.

You may also consider taking a look at [Tableau](http://www.tableausoftware.com/) if you want the end users/decision makers making their own dashboards.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'll take a look at the resources you've pointed out.